# Installing Wine and missing dependancies

Tags: wine, dependencies

Hi all im new to linux and am trying to install wine in order to set up some servers that require windows .bat files but everytime I go throught the process decribed on the website i get to the final part of the installation

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

and it returns:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 4.8~disco)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

no matter what fix i use to correct this it does not work, does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Wine will probably not run what you want but you can try. Why not install the version already in the repositories? Why are you adding PPAs?

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu are you running? What is "the process described on the website?" Can you link to the exact instructions you followed?